# Categories columns in second row to the first row in DataFrame Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I had this database:

```
Unnamed=0          2001 2002 2003

General             456  567  543
Cleaning            234  234  344
```

After transpose data, I got the variables in the second row in Jupyter Notebook:

```
df = df.T.rename_axis('Date').reset_index()
df
   Date       1         2
1           General  Cleaning
2  2001      456       234
3  2002      567       234
4  2003      543       344
```

How do I place them in the first row in the DataFrame so I can group and manipulate the values?

```
   Date     General  Cleaning
1  2001      456       234
2  2002      567       234
3  2003      543       344
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close with the attempt you showed above. Instead, [reset the index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to move the dates from the index to the first column, and then [rename](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) that date column from `index` to `Date`:

```
df = df.T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Date'})
df
```

Output:

```
   Date General Cleaning
0  2001     456      234
1  2002     567      234
2  2003     543      344
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply drop row 1 and rename columns.

```
df.drop(1, axis=0, inplace=True)
df.columns= ['Date', 'General', 'Cleaning']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[2001,2002,2003],[456,567,543],[234,234,344]],index=[0,'General','Cleaning'])
```

Just do it:

```
df = df.T.copy().rename(columns={0:'Date'})
```